# Codeigniter PDO error connection Notice: Trying to get property of non-object. Filename pdo/pdo_driver.php

Tags: postgresql, codeigniter, pdo

I'm trying to insert data in pdo pgsql (second database) but i'm gettig this Notice: Trying to get property of non-object. Filename: pdo/pdo_driver.php.

Here is my connection to database:

```
$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;

$db['pdo_email'] = array(
    'hostname' => 'pgsql:host=00.00.00.00;dbname=db_name;port=5432',
    'username' => 'user',
    'password' => 'password',
    'database' => 'db_name',
    'dbdriver' => 'pdo',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

And in my model i have this in function (just important stuff here, is incomplete):

```
public function send_email_platforma($to,$subject,$message,$type='html') {
$pdo = $this->load->database('pdo_email', TRUE);
        $data = array(
                'to' => $to,
                'sl' => $subject,
                'mesaj' => $message,
                'format_mesaj' => $type,
                'tip_mesaj' => $camp_update,
                'confirmare_cont' => '0',
                'portal' => 'website',
                'data_email' => date('Y-m-d'),
                'ora_email' => date('H:i:s')
            );
                        
             
            $pdo->insert('table_name', $data) or die($pdo->error());
            $insert_id = $pdo->insert_id();
            return $insert_id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

MY DATABASE CONNECTIVITY SETTINGS WITH POSTGRES :

```
$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;

    $db['default'] = array(
        'dsn'   => '',
        'hostname' => 'pgsql:host=localhost;dbname=Absences_DB',
        'username' => 'postgres',
        'password' => 'marc',
        'database' => 'Absences_DB',
        'dbdriver' => 'pdo',
        'dbprefix' => '',
        'pconnect' => FALSE,
        'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
        'cache_on' => FALSE,
        'cachedir' => '',
        'char_set' => 'utf8',
        'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
        'swap_pre' => '',
        'encrypt' => FALSE,
        'compress' => FALSE,
        'stricton' => FALSE,
        'failover' => array(),
        'save_queries' => TRUE
     );
```

you should verify if the pdo driver is enable in the php.ini files

Comment: pdo driver is enable.. I think the real problem is CI version : 2.1.4..

Comment: make sure the pdo driver appears on the PHP info page

Comment: pdo driver appears on the PHP info :(

Comment: from the documentation : Some database drivers (such as PDO, PostgreSQL, Oracle, ODBC) might require a full DSN string to be provided. If that is the case, you should use the ‘DSN’ configuration setting, as if you’re using the driver’s underlying native PHP extension, like this:  $default['DSN'] = 'pgsql:host=localhost;port=5432;dbname=database_name';

Comment: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/configuration.html